“OperationalError: Could not translate host name “db” to address" in Dockerized Django App with Datadog
I have a very complex django project that uses postgresql as database, where I have setup datadog to send traces and events. It works fine locally and I am receiving traces and events in datadog. However, if I try to run my app using docker, it won't send traces and events to datadog. Following is my docker-compose.yml file where datadog integration is borrowed from here.
docker-compose.yml
services:
  db:
    image: ankane/pgvector
    env_file:
      - ./docker/env.db
    volumes:
      - pgvector_db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/prod.Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./docker/env.db
      - ./.env
    container_name: scooprank
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/opt/code/static
      - shm:/dev/shm
      - save_drivers:/opt/code/save_drivers
      - save_models:/opt/code/save_models
    command: ./docker/scripts/run-gunicorn
    depends_on:
      - db
    network_mode: host

  ddagent:
    image: datadog/docker-dd-agent
    environment:
      - DD_BIND_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - DD_API_KEY=${DATADOG_API_KEY}
      - DD_APM_RECEIVER_SOCKET=/tmp/ddagent/trace.sock
      - DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC=true
    ports:
      - "8127:8126"

  news_scraper:
    image: scooprank-app
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    container_name: news_scraper
    command: python manage.py news_scraper
    depends_on:
      - app
    restart: always

volumes:
  static_volume:
  shm:
  save_drivers:
  save_models:
  pgvector_db_data:


I added network_mode: host as suggested by this answer. I then tried this solution on a simple dummy project having sqlite3 as database and with this docker-compose file, I am receiving traces and events. But if I try to use it in my main project, I can do docker compose build and docker compose up, but when I migrate, I get error.
(.venv) prixite@prixite-Latitude-5410:~/Desktop/scooprank$ docker compose -f docker-compose.yml exec app ./manage.py migrate

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 275, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/utils.py", line 1711, in runner
    return sentry_patched_function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py", line 659, in connect
    return real_connect(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 277, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/code/./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/code/./manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 107, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 100, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 36, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1617, in check
    *cls._check_constraints(databases),
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 2467, in _check_constraints
    connection.features.supports_nulls_distinct_unique_constraints
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/features.py", line 141, in is_postgresql_15
    return self.connection.pg_version >= 150000
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 438, in pg_version
    with self.temporary_connection():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 691, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 316, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 292, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 274, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 275, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/utils.py", line 1711, in runner
    return sentry_patched_function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py", line 659, in connect
    return real_connect(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 277, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Sentry is attempting to send 2 pending events
Waiting up to 2 seconds
Press Ctrl-C to quit

Following are my other files in case these are required:
env.db
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
POSTGRES_DB=scooprank
POSTGRES_USER=postgres

prod.Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11.5

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8

# Add buster Postgres repo. This is necessary to install postgresql-client-12
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ buster-pgdg main" | tee  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    postgresql-client-12 \
    build-essential \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libpango1.0-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libgif-dev \
    librsvg2-dev \
    g++ \
    xvfb

RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN pip install pip==24.0

WORKDIR /opt/code

COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json

RUN npm install

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN python -m nltk.downloader punkt averaged_perceptron_tagger wordnet omw-1.4

COPY . ./

.env file
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:secret@db/scooprank
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=http://127.0.0.1:8006
DATADOG_API_KEY=<my_api_key>
DATADOG_APP_KEY=<my_app_key>
STATSD_HOST=127.0.0.1
STATSD_PORT=8125

settings.py
# Database 

DATABASES = {"default": env.dj_db_url("DATABASE_URL")}

# Datadog

if not DEBUG and env.str("DATADOG_API_KEY"):
    DATADOG_OPTIONS = {
        "api_key": env.str("DATADOG_API_KEY"),
        "app_key": env.str("DATADOG_APP_KEY"),
        "statsd_host": env.str("STATSD_HOST"),
        "statsd_port": env.int("STATSD_PORT"),
    }

    initialize(**DATADOG_OPTIONS)

I tried changing my database url to use localhost instead of db but no luck. I also tried adding networks in my services but no use. If I remove ddtrace service and network_mode: host, my app will work fine but without sending traces and events to datadog.

I think the primary issue is that your Django application container can't resolve the hostname db when it's running the migrate command. This is often due to network configuration issues within Docker Compose.

Yes, correct. If I remove the network_mode: host and ddagent service, I will not get db error while migrating. But I won't be getting any traces in datadog.

Remove network_mode: host to ensure Docker’s network works correctly.
Ensure all services are on the same Docker network.
Configure the Datadog agent correctly to receive traces from the application.

I tried this also. I removed network_mode: host and it didn't sent any traces or events to datadog. This datadog agent configuration worked for me on dummy project after many failed attempts. I tried almost every possible github repo available having datadog integration but only this worked for me on dummy project.

Remove network_mode: host, that puts your app outside of the network created by docker compose by default and therefore your app cannot access Postgres, which is on the default network.
Set env variable DD_TRACE_AGENT_HOSTNAME=ddagent on the app service. Most likely this is not the only change required in your compose file; see below.

Refer to https://github.com/DataDog/trace-examples for more details. The repo has a dedicated Django section

https://github.com/DataDog/trace-examples/tree/master/python/django

which contains example compose file

https://github.com/DataDog/trace-examples/blob/master/python/django/django-tutorial/docker-compose.yml
https://github.com/DataDog/trace-examples/blob/master/python/django/django-realworld/docker-compose.yml.


Thanks for the reply. I will surely test this approach and will get back to you.

Since I have postgresql as database, Only the repo by the name tutorial is relevant to me. I tried same settings and configuration. But it is still not sending any traces to datadog. Removing network_mode:host won't send traces and using it will give db error.
